# SQL - Listing all prerequisites (Like a loop)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

(I'm using SQL Plus, although I don't think that would matter too much)

Okay my database structure looks similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE MODULE (
  module_code       INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (module_code)
);

CREATE TABLE PREREQUISITES (
  module_code       INT,
  prerequisite_code VARCHAR(6),
  FOREIGN KEY (module_code) REFERENCES MODULE(module_code),
  FOREIGN KEY (prerequisite_code) REFERENCES MODULE(module_code)
);
```

So the data may look like this:

```
MODULE:
5
15
20
100

PREREQUISITES:
100  20
100  15
15   5
```

My question is, is there a way to list all prerequisites for a module (e.g. prerequisites of 100 is: 20, 15 & 5 (because 15 has a prerequisite of 5) or must this be done programmatically.

I'm also aware there could be circular references. Again I can think of a way to do this programmatically but is there a way to detect this using just SQL.

Comment: Whenever there is a circular reference, the people who designed the relationships need a spanking because they're essentially preventing anyone from learning everything within the ecosystem and indirectly asking people to learn it elsewhere. sgeddes has a good answer though

Comment: How would you recommend such a table should be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the RDBMS you are using maters completely for what you are trying to accomplish.  You are storing your hierarchical data in an `adjacency list` model.  Since you are using `oracle`, you can use `CONNECT BY` to traverse the tree:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PREREQUISITES
START WITH module_code = 100
CONNECT BY module_code = PRIOR prerequisite_code
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67c61e/1)

And here's a good article on the subject: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/28/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-oracle/

---

If duplicates and infinite loops are potential concerns, you can use `nocylcle` to prevent the infinite loops and a subquery to return the `distinct` results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT module_code, prerequisite_code FROM PREREQUISITES) T
START WITH module_code = 100
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE module_code = PRIOR prerequisite_code
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e345e/2)

Comment: Can you somehow bring in NOCYCLE and DISTINCT to prevent loops?

Comment: I was so not taught this! Thanks. Does a similar feature appear in MySQL by any chance. Also is this at all possible using vanilla SQL.